# SQL Query Eliminate Multiple Table Calls of Same Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that I need to improve performance on.  The biggest issue is that it's calling the same table multiple times, and I'm trying to see if there is a better way to execute it.

```
SELECT tc.chargesID
      ,p1.payerID as paymentPlan_Payer_1
      ,p2.payerID as paymentPlan_Payer_2
      ,p3.payerID as paymentPlan_Payer_3
      ,p4.payerID as paymentPlan_Payer_4
FROM TableCharges tc
LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc se ON c.chargesID  = se.salesencounterID

LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc_Payer sep1 ON sep.salesencounterID = se.salesencounterID and sep.salesCode = 1
LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc_Payer sep2 ON sep.salesencounterID = se.salesencounterID and sep.salesCode = 2
LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc_Payer sep3 ON sep.salesencounterID = se.salesencounterID and sep.salesCode = 3
LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc_Payer sep4 ON sep.salesencounterID = se.salesencounterID and sep.salesCode = 4

LEFT JOIN payer p1 ON sep1.payerID = p1.payerID
LEFT JOIN payer p2 ON sep2.payerID = p2.payerID
LEFT JOIN payer p3 ON sep3.payerID = p3.payerID
LEFT JOIN payer p4 ON sep4.payerID = p4.payerID
```

Let me know what you guys think.

Comment: Self-joins are not in and of themselves a bad thing, so I doubt having all those joins is really your issue.  It would help us if you post your table schema and the actual execution plan generated for the dataset giving you problems (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).  If you are suffering from performance problems here then likely you just need better indexing.

Comment: Why do you need to self-join, can you not just join once and use `and sep.salesCode BETWEEN 1 AND 4`

Comment: If we do it that way, we end up getting duplicates.  I think this is why the original developer created it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just couldn't let this go.  This is how you solve this.

```
SELECT tc.chargesID, 

MAX(CASE WHEN sep1.salesCode = 1 THEN p1.payerID ELSE NULL END) as paymentPlan_Payer_1, 
MAX(CASE WHEN sep1.salesCode = 2 THEN p1.payerID ELSE NULL END) as paymentPlan_Payer_2, 
MAX(CASE WHEN sep1.salesCode = 3 THEN p1.payerID ELSE NULL END) as paymentPlan_Payer_3, 
MAX(CASE WHEN sep1.salesCode = 4 THEN p1.payerID ELSE NULL END) as paymentPlan_Payer_4

FROM TableCharges tc

LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc se ON c.chargesID  = se.salesencounterID

LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc_Payer sep1 ON sep.salesencounterID = se.salesencounterID and sep.salesCode IN (1,2,3,4)

LEFT JOIN payer p1 ON sep1.payerID = p1.payerID

GROUP BY tc.chargesID
```

Now I'm getting exactly the rows I was looking for.  I managed to eliminate the multiple table calls which is the primary thing I wanted from this.

Answer (score 0):

In line with what @Charlieface said try just joining to **Sales_Enc_Payer** once and also moving the salesCode = 1 join filters to the joins with the corresponding payer table instances like this...

```
SELECT
          tc.chargesID
        , p1.payerID AS paymentPlan_Payer_1
        , p2.payerID AS paymentPlan_Payer_2
        , p3.payerID AS paymentPlan_Payer_3
        , p4.payerID AS paymentPlan_Payer_4
FROM      TableCharges    tc
LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc       se ON tc.chargesID          = se.salesencounterID
LEFT JOIN Sales_Enc_Payer sep ON sep.salesencounterID = se.salesencounterID
LEFT JOIN payer           p1 ON sep.payerID           = p1.payerID
                            AND sep.salesCode         = 1
LEFT JOIN payer           p2 ON sep.payerID           = p2.payerID
                            AND sep.salesCode         = 2
LEFT JOIN payer           p3 ON sep.payerID           = p3.payerID
                            AND sep.salesCode         = 3
LEFT JOIN payer           p4 ON sep.payerID           = p4.payerID
                            AND sep.salesCode         = 4;
```

Comment: Ya my thing is that I'm trying to get rid of calling the same tables multiple times.  Cause right now I get these results:

Without the payer columns in select I get let's say 100 rows
With the payer columns by calling the tables only 1 time, I get like 140+ rows
With the payer columns by calling the tables multiple times, I get the 100 rows I'm looking for.

Comment: So you must have multiple records in your Sales_Enc_Payer table for some payerID values with different salesCode values? Is that true? Does that matter?